# Fixing broken media URLs after moving to Wordpress Multisite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, wordpress

I recently moved all my blogs into a single Wordpress Multisite installation. However, I know have the problem that media links are broken - not only in some of my blog posts, but also across the internet whereever I embedded images from my media library.

This is the regular URL
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/filename.gif

This is the URL after installing MU: 
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/12/filename.gif
where the following are variable:
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/[siteID]/[year]/[month]/[filename].[ext]

Is it possible to fix this problem with htaccess URL forwarding and regular expressions? How exactly would the htaccess command and the regular expression look like? (Unfortunately I'm somewhat illeterate when it comes to regex)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/sites/2/$1? [R,L]
```

If the url doesn't contain `wp-content/uploads/sites/2/` then it will add the `sites/2/` to the url

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way with regex to make it so that the 2 can be any number? The above was just an example, there will probably be other sites with other MU-ID's in the future.

Comment: How do you know what image is on which site?